# UIView with shadow and rounder corners - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, rounded-corners

I have a table view cell inside a view. I want this view to have a shadow and rounded corners. For this reason I created a class:

```
class UIViewWithShadowAndRoundedCorner: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var roundedView: UIView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.addShadow()
    }

    public func addShadow() {
        self.roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        self.roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addShadow()
    }
}
```

The view inside the table view cell is a `UIViewWithShadowAndRoundedCorner` but I get this result (view hasn't got rounded corners, only shadow):

[image: shadow but no rounded corners]

If I create another project with only one `UIViewController` and inside it an instance of `UIViewWithShadowAndRoundedCorner` I get this (result that I want to get):

[image: desired result shadow + rounded corner view]

Why do I get different results with same view type?

Comment: what is roundedView? why wouldn't you round the corners of UIViewWithShadowAndRoundedCorner itself?

Comment: I want that the view is with shadow and with rounded corners and I find a solution that use a view with shadow (UIViewWithShadowAndRoundedCorner) and a subview with rounded corner. Have you another solution?

Comment: Bit confused where the cell is in your hierarchy. Is the `UIViewWithShadowAndRoundedCorner` inside the cell or is it vice versa?